# Header component is losing state on refresh

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs

When a user logs on, their name is displayed in the navbar. However, when the user refreshes the page, their name disappears.

I have tried changing isLoginNameSubject from a Subject to a ReplaySubject, and a BehaviorSubject.

Authservice: When user submits form invokes login(), which creates two side effects, store token in LocalStorage, uses subset of the response to populate the navbar (Header).

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private uri: string;
  public isLoginNameSubject =  new BehaviorSubject<Object>('test');


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config: Configuration,
    private router: Router ) {
    this.uri = this.config.getConfigOption('apiUri');
  }

   public login = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return this.http.post(
      `${this.uri}/authenticate?login=${email}&password=${password}`,
      undefined
    ).pipe(
      tap(res => localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res))),
      tap(res => this.isLoginNameSubject.next(res.user.data)))
  }

  public loginName():  Observable<object> {
   return this.isLoginNameSubject.asObservable().pipe(share())
  }
```

Header TS: I inject loginName() to hide the implementation of the Subject.

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public userName$: Observable<object>


  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private config: Configuration) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.userName$ = this.authService.loginName()
  }

}
```

Header template:

```
<strong *ngIf="userName$ | async as user">
              {{user.name}} 
            </strong>
```

When the user logs in, user is taken to a welcome page. Navbar/header contents is populated with content from res.user.data, specifically the users name. When user refreshes the page, I expect the users name to continue to be displayed. In actual fact it does not. It seems as if res.user.data is lost on refresh.

Initially I reasoned that this was due to isLoginNameSubject being merely a Subject. On refresh the page is reloaded, but there is no login event. I tried using isLoginNameSubject as a BehaviorSubject, as I understood that it emits last value, but the issue persists.

Comment: Your service only appears to store the `res.user.data` to local storage. Shouldn't it also read from it in the constructor/init to check if the data is already available and then pass it in the observable ? Also, does the `login` method get called on page refresh ? So no way for the service to know if the data is in local storage.

Comment: @ashish.gd, what is best way to detect refresh? Check for NavigationStart?

Comment: Yes, `NavigationStart` should be enough to understand a page refresh. But given your code, it would add a router dependency in your service.  You can simply check in the constructor during the service initialisation if the data is present in local storage and pass into the observable if found. This logic works assuming you clear user data on logout or check token validity each time the app loads.